# C# export list items to data table? change date time

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sql-server

I'm doing an export to a table from the SharePoint list, I do not understand why the date changes when unloading into a table, tell me what's wrong with my code?

[image]

```
 public void SPExportCalendar() {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp:7000/sites/test");
            Web web = context.Web;
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("test");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "";
            ListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(allitems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            DataSet EmpDataSet = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da;

            cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SQLServer;Initial Catalog=DataCalendar;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            cn.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [dbo].[Calendar_SP]", cn);
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Fill(EmpDataSet, "Calendar_SP");

            DataTable table = EmpDataSet.Tables[0];
            foreach (ListItem listitem in allitems)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row["Date"] = DateTime.Parse(listitem["DateCreate"].ToString());
                table.Rows.Add(row);
                builder.GetInsertCommand();
            }
            da.Update(EmpDataSet, "Calendar_SP");
            Console.WriteLine("Export SPList OK");
        }
```

Comment: maybe try converting the date object to utc before adding it to database?

Comment: @DamjanTomic maybe, do you have a sample example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
row["Date"] = System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Convert.ToDateTime(listitem["DateCreate"].ToString()));
```